# Scoreboard digit recognition using OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

I am trying to extract numbers from a typical scoreboard that you would find at a high school gym. I have each number in a digital "alarm clock" font and have managed to perspective correct, threshold and extract a given digit from the video feed

[image: Sample input]

Here's a sample of my template input

[image: Template input]

My problem is that no one classification method will accurately determine all digits 0-9. I have tried several methods

1) Tesseract OCR - this one consistently messes up on 4 and frequently returns weird results. Just using the command line version. If I actually try to train it on an "alarm clock" font, I get unknown character every time.

2) kNearest with OpenCV - I search a database consisting of my template images (0-9) and see which one is nearest. I frequently get confusion between 3/1 and 7/1

3) cvMatchShapes - this one is fairly bad, it usually can't tell the difference between 2 of the digits for each input digit

4) Tangent Distance - This one is the closest, but the smallest tangent distance between the input and my templates ends up mapping "7" to "1" every time

I'm really at a loss to get a classification algorithm for such a simple problem. I feel I have cleaned up the input fairly well and it's a fairly simple case for classification but I can't get anything reliable enough to actually use in practice. Any ideas about where to look for classification algorithms, or how to use them correctly would be appreciated. Am I not cleaning up the input? What about a better input database? I don't know what else I'd use for input, each digit and template looks spot on at this point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The classical digit recognition, which should work well in this case is to crop the image just around the digit and resize it to 4x4 pixels.

A Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT) can be used to further slim down the search space. You could select the first 4-6 values.

With those values, train a classifier. SVM is a good one, readily available in OpenCV.

It is not as simple as emma's or martin suggestions, but it's more elegant and, I think, more robust.

Given the width/height ratio of your input, you may choose a different resolution, like 3x4. Choose the smallest one that retains readable digits.

Comment: I used a 3x5 image (similar to rows/columns in digital display) and it works great with kNearest searching. Dead on. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Given the highly regular nature of your input, you could define a set of 7 target areas of the image to check. Each area should encompass some significant portion of one of the 7 segments of each digital of the display, but not overlap.

You can then check each area and average the color / brightness of the pixels in to to generate a probability for a given binary state. If your probability is high on all areas you can then easily figure out what the digit is.

It's not as elegant as a pure ML type algorithm, but ML is far more suited to inputs which are not regular, and in this case that does not seem to apply - so you trade elegance for accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

Might sound silly but have you tried simply checking for  black bars vertically  and then horizontally in the top and bottom halfs - left and right of the centerline ?

Comment: I implemented your simple idea for a problem I was working on and it works fine. Just had to check for big black bars vertically from the left, while also capturing the first vertical bar 'stats'.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying text recognition with Tesseract, try passing not one digit, but a number of duplicated digits, sometimes it could produce better results, [here's the example](http://groups.google.com/group/tesseract-ocr/browse_thread/thread/256ef1287fe91ff5/94256d4c8ef01804?show_docid=94256d4c8ef01804).
However, if you're planning a business software, you may want to have a look at a commercial OCR SDK. For example, try [ABBYY FineReader Engine](http://www.abbyy.com/ocr_sdk/). It's not affordable for free to use applications, but when it comes to business, it can a good value to your product. As far as i know, ABBYY provides the best OCR quality, for example check out http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2010-06/15-linux_ocr_software_comparison

Answer (score 0):

You want your scorecard image inputs S feeding an algorithm that maps them to {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.

Let V denote the set of n-tuples of integers.

Construct an algorithm α that maps each image S to a n-tuple

(k<sub>1</sub>,k<sub>2</sub>,...,k<sub>n</sub>)

that can differentiate between two different scoreboard digits.

If you can specify the range of α then you only have to collect the vectors in V that correspond to a digit in order to solve the problem.

I've applied this idea using Martin Beckett's [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8070447/8929814) and it works. My initial attempt was a simple injection into a 2-tuple by vertical left-to-right summing, with the first integer a image column offset and the second integer was the length of a 'nice' vertical line.

This did not work - images for 6 and 8 would map to the same vectors. So I needed another *mini-info-capture* for my digit input types (they are not scoreboard) and a 3-tuple info vector does the trick.